# My schema location and address location changes when I deploy the web services in my website

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I have defined a WSDL in my website it goes like http://sitename.com/getmessage?wsdl.
I can access this wsdl by going to that address. But when I open the wsdl . The schema location and the address location which should be the same as the URL provided is shown as localhost:8084/somepath/getmessage.
Which is causing error when a client tries to access the give some input.
It runs fine on my local. But after deployment it gets changed.

Comment: Are you perhaps deploying it differently, e.g. on your local you access webapp directly, but in deployment it's behind an Apache web server that proxies the requests to your webapp server (e.g. Tomcat)?

Comment: No I use tomcat at my local too. And yes I guess our company uses Apache web server. But why can I access it using the URL but the address and schema location changes

Comment: I am a rookie at this so I hope I am not wrong. But I desperately need to solve this

Comment: The dynamically generated WSDL will insert the actual URL used to access the webapp, so when you access it directly, the WSDL will have the URL path you gave. When Apache proxies to Tomcat, it changes the URL, so Tomcat sees a different URL than the one actually used/needed to access the webapp. The Apache proxying needs to tell Tomcat what the real URL is. I usually use AJP for proxying, because it takes care of it. Whoever set up the server needs to figure out how Apache can tell Tomcat the real URL in your setup.

Comment: Hello Andreas thanks for the quick replies . Can you give me some ideas. I don't think he knows what he is doing . (The server guy)

Comment: You either use the Tomcat AJP connector (standard Tomcat `server.xml` has one) with Apache's [`mod_proxy_ajp`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html), *or* you use `mod_proxy` (which I believe you're doing right now) but configure Tomcat [correctly](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/proxy-howto.html#Apache_1.3_Proxy_Support).

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing I can do at the code to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello Andreas. When I saved the wsdl file and changed the address it is working fine. Is there a way by which I can permanently change the wsdl content?